# how do I use VBSedit to create an 8MB text file?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I need to create files of various sizes. How can I create one thats 8MB?

(It would be nice to create a HTA application and we specify the file size)

I can create the HTA application that will be more user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a (text) file and write 8 mb data:

```
dir
...
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

>> Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> oFS.CreateTextFile("8mb.txt", True).Write String(8000000,"x")

dir
...
17.12.2012  18:00         8.000.000 8mb.txt
```

Comment: @CocoaDev - You don't need to be told, because you asked the String() function to generate 8 mb data.